# What is the difference between array gain and diversity gain?

Tags: array-signal-processing, mimo, diversity

In a multi-antenna system, we often mention diversity gain in fading channels. I am doing simulations with multiple antenna settings at the receiver considering TDLC channel, for example, 1rx, 2rx, 4rx..

The performance improvement I am seeing in the case of more antenna --> should I call it an array gain or diversity gain?

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, the definitions of these concepts are not perfectly agreed on by everyone. This is what I think is the most popular interpretation:

- **Diversity gain** is the gain in SNR at the receiver, obtained by taking advantage of any kind of diversity: transmit, receive, frequency, space-time, polarization... etc.
- **Array gain** is a specific case of diversity gain, obtained when the receiver has multiple antennas and it manages to coherently add the signals received by each antenna.

So, you can call it a diversity gain in general, or an array gain if you want to be more explicit.